# How to add a new column with values based on conditions of other existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is the current df_treatments.

[image]

I want to add a new field "treatment_type" with values that should be based on the values in columns (metformin, glipizide, insulin):

("value of treatment_type": (value of metformin,value of glipizide, value of insulin))

```
"No Treatment" (NO, NO, NO)
"Metformin" (YES, NO, NO)
"Glipizide" (NO, YES, NO)
"Insulin" (NO, NO, YES)
"Metformin-Glipizide" (YES, YES, NO)
"Metformin-Insulin" (YES, NO, YES)
"Glipizide-Insulin" (NO, YES, YES)
"Metformin-Glipizide-Insulin" (YES, YES, YES)
```

How can I do this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approaches. One is to use a dictionary to store your treatments and conditions:

```
d = {"No Treatment": ('NO', 'NO', 'NO'),
     "Metformin": ('YES', 'NO', 'NO')
     "Glipizide": ('NO', 'YES', 'NO'),
     ...}
```

Then iterate your dictionary and update your series:

```
arr = df[['metformin', 'glipizide', 'insulin']].values

for treatment, flags in d.items():
    df.loc[(arr == flags).all(1), 'treatment_type'] = treatment
```

The only improvement I suggest is to convert all `'NO'` / `'YES'` values to Boolean `False` / `True`. This will be considerably more efficient as Boolean series support vectorised operations.

Comment: d = {"No Treatment": ('NO', 'NO', 'NO'),
     "Metformin": ('YES', 'NO', 'NO'),
     "Glipizide": ('NO', 'YES', 'NO'),
     "Metformin-Glipizide": ('YES', 'YES', 'NO'),
     "Metformin-Insulin": ('YES', 'NO', 'YES'),
     "Glipizide-Insulin": ('NO', 'YES', 'YES'),
     "Metformin-Glipizide-Insulin": ('YES', 'YES', 'YES')
    }
arr = df_treatments[['metformin', 'glipizide', 'insulin']].values

for treatment, flags in d.items():
    df_treatments.loc[(arr == flags).all(1), 'treatment_type'] = df_treatments

Comment: I ran it like that, and now it shows NaN under treatment_type :( what did I do wrong?

Comment: That last line looks wrong, you need `= treatments` as per my example. `= df_treatments` makes no sense.